# Twilio API & Exponential Backoff when sending bulk SMS with Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, exponential-backoff

I am working on a bulk SMS application that will send one message to a group of people in case of an emergency. I have reviewed the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js) and implemented their code, at which point I was getting a 429 error from the API. So I've added the exponential backoff code to prevent that, but when I run the script, it's only sending to the second number listed in the array.

```
const accountSid = '[ACCOUNT SID]';
const authToken = '[AUTH TOKEN]';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

var numbersToMessage = ["+1800XXXXXXX", "+1888XXXXXXX"]

numbersToMessage.forEach(function(number){
  var message = client.messages.create({
    body: 'This is test #2 from August 21, 2020.',
    from: '[TWILIO SENDER NUMBER]',
    statusCallback: '[PIPEDREAM API URL]',
    to: number
  })
  .then(message => console.log(message.status))
  return((err) => {
  // assumes that the error is "request made too soon"
  backoffTime *= 2;
  i--;
  console.log(err);
  return delay(backoffTime);
});
  done();
});
```

Exponential backoff is completely new to me, so I'm fairly certain that's where the issue is, but that's as far as I get. I've tried using the npm package [exponential-backoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exponential-backoff), too, without any luck.

Comment: How many people are in the group, in other words, how many messages are in the bulk?

Comment: @AlexBaban Approximately 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear this is not "exponential backoff" but it should work with about 100 numbers.

Replace with your Twilio credentials, add your numbers to the array, replace `PIPEDREAM_API_URL`. All your 100 messages should be queued at Twilio in about 30 seconds.

The response `message.sid` from Twilio means that the message was added to the sending queue, not that the message was actually sent.

```js
const accountSid = 'AC...';
const authToken = '4f...';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const TWILIO_SENDER_NUMBER = '+1...';
const TEXT_TO_SEND = 'This is test #2 from August 21, 2020.';
const PIPEDREAM_API_URL = '...';

// about 100 numbers
let numbersToMessage = [
    "+1...",
    "+1...",
    "+1...",
    // "+1...",

];

function sendAllMessagesWithTwilio(data) {

    // stop condition, nothing left in the array of numbers
    if (data.length === 0) {
        console.log('............... DONE');
        return;
    }

    // take the first number from the array of numbers
    let _number = data.shift();
    console.log(_number);

    client.messages
        .create({
            to: _number,
            from: TWILIO_SENDER_NUMBER,
            body: TEXT_TO_SEND,
            statusCallback: PIPEDREAM_API_URL
        })
        .then((message) => {
            // after Twilio responds, send the next message
            console.log(`${message.sid}`);
            // recursive call of function, pass the remaining numbers as argument
            // use setTimeout() to slow down, 300 milliseconds between requests
            setTimeout(sendAllMessagesWithTwilio.bind(null, data), 300);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // if an error is sent back from Twilio
            console.error(err);
        });

}

// first call of recursive function
// takes the initial array of numbers as argument
console.log('BEGIN ...............')
sendAllMessagesWithTwilio(numbersToMessage);
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great!